# Mapping correct connection string in multi-database environment & maintaining membership with session state of logged in user once at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, web-config

In my web application I have Super Admin [MASTER_DB] module where we create multiple clients & those clients can have multiple users. For each client we have different database. I have maintained all details of clients in MASTER_DB. We input connection string from super admin for each client. We create one ADMIN USER from superadmin & with the help of that user client creates another users. Those users must be created in that client's database & all related activities should be performed on that database.

I am able to create ADMIN USER from super admin to particular clients db by using SqlMembershipProvider &  SqlRoleProvider classes & updating Connection String runtime in web.config. And updated client's details using particular clients stored connection string & passing to dbContext.

```html
public partial class DBEntities : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
    {
        public DBEntities(string ConnectionString)
            : base(ConnectionString)
        {

        }
    }
```

We have same link for all users to access our web application. I am implementing to change the web.config files connection string at runtime once the user is validated from MASTER_DB & map that user login to particular DB. But changing connection string in web.config at runtime is not seems to be a good solution & its not working perfectly.

So anybody if implemented this scenario please guide me for the best approach to implement this; where once I get correct connection string I should map that user to correct database & apply membership functions on it. 
I am using Visual Studio 2012 & Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating single edmx for all.

If yes then please seperate edmax for all database and do database operation using their context.

Comment: Thanx for reply. I am creating two edmx files. One for Super Admin. And one for clients. I am just referencing client's data layer .dll (In data layer I have included the edmx file) in Super Admin. And by using Entity ModelName am passing connection string to dbContext to store particular details to particular client's database.    
--for Super admin  

 ` using (DBEntitiesSuperAdmin _db = new DBEntitiesSuperAdmin()) { }`   

 --For client  

 using (DBClientsEntities _db = new ClientsEntities(ConnectionString)) { }